# creating MLP in python showing error

Tags: python, opencv

Iam a newbie in neural networks while creating MLP in python using opencv 3.1.0 error pops.The code is 
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import glob

```
print 'Loading training data...'
e0 = cv2.getTickCount()

# load training data
image_array = np.zeros((1, 38400))
label_array = np.zeros((1, 4), 'float')
training_data = glob.glob('training_data/*.npz')

for single_npz in training_data:
with np.load(single_npz) as data:
    print data.files
    train_temp = data['train']
    train_labels_temp = data['train_labels']
    print train_temp.shape
    print train_labels_temp.shape
image_array = np.vstack((image_array, train_temp))
label_array = np.vstack((label_array, train_labels_temp))

train = image_array[1:, :]
train_labels = label_array[1:, :]
print train.shape
print train_labels.shape

e00 = cv2.getTickCount()
time0 = (e00 - e0)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
print 'Loading image duration:', time0

# set start time
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()

# create MLP
layer_sizes = np.int32([38400, 32, 4])
model = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()
model.create(layer_sizes)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 500, 0.0001)
criteria2 = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 100, 0.001)
params = dict(term_crit = criteria,
           train_method = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_BACKPROP,
           bp_dw_scale = 0.001,
           bp_moment_scale = 0.0 )

print 'Training MLP ...'
num_iter = model.train(train, train_labels,  params = params )

# set end time
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
time = (e2 - e1)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
print 'Training duration:', time

# save param
model.save('mlp_xml/mlp.xml')

print 'Ran for %d iterations' % num_iter

ret, resp = model.predict(train)
prediction = resp.argmax(-1)
  print 'Prediction:', prediction
  true_labels = train_labels.argmax(-1)
  print 'True labels:', true_labels

  print 'Testing...'
  train_rate = np.mean(prediction == true_labels)
  print 'Train rate: %f:' % (train_rate*100)
```

this is the error
       AttributeError: 'cv2.ml_ANN_MLP' object has no attribute 'create'

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [code sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/letter_recog.py#L125), I would suggest setting the number of layers as follows:

```
model.setLayerSizes(layer_sizes)
```

You can also have a look at the [Learning OpenCV 3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iNlOCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA214) book.

I can't seem to be able to find a proper complete doc at the minute, but for the record here's what `dir(model)` gives:

- calcError
- clear
- empty
- getBackpropMomentumScale
- getBackpropWeightScale
- getDefaultName
- getLayerSizes
- getRpropDW0
- getRpropDWMax
- getRpropDWMin
- getRpropDWMinus
- getRpropDWPlus
- getTermCriteria
- getTrainMethod
- getVarCount
- getWeights
- isClassifier
- isTrained
- predict
- save
- setActivationFunction
- setBackpropMomentumScale
- setBackpropWeightScale
- setLayerSizes
- setRpropDW0
- setRpropDWMax
- setRpropDWMin
- setRpropDWMinus
- setRpropDWPlus
- setTermCriteria
- setTrainMethod
- train