# ANN_MLP() not working with Opencv 3.1.0 Dev (python)

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, neural-network

I have been working on Neural Networks Using OpenCV

From the documentation I have learned that instead of *cv2.ANN_MLP*

We have to use *cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()*

But what I don't get is how do I give the layer size?

Here is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

training_data = np.zeros((1,307200))
labels = np.zeros((1,4),'float')
train = glob.glob('training.npz')
print train
for i in train:
    with np.load(i) as data:
        print data.files
        training_temp = data['training_image_array']
        labels_temp = data['output_array']
    training_data = np.vstack((training_data,training_temp))
    labels = np.vstack((labels,labels_temp))

training_data = training_data[1:,:]
labels = labels[1:, :]

print training_data.shape
print labels.shape

e1 = cv2.getTickCount()

layer_size = np.int32([307200,32,4])

neural = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()
nerual.create(layer_size)
```

This gives me an error.

If anyone has an idea on what to do, Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is edit your post and specify the error you get. Here are two hints nonetheless:

1. There is a typo in the last line: *nerual* instead of *neural*.
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051837/777285) might help with setting the number of layers.